# Security automation with powershell

Tags: powershell, security, permissions, active-directory

I have users in an Active Directory, I created a GPO (Group Policy Object), which groups these users.

I do want to know is there a way to link the Active Directory Group Policy Object to SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) with PowerShell or any development tools.

The idea is this users within the Active Directory manipulates data within the database, and its causing a breach in database security.

I want to link the SA account of the SQL SERVER to the Active Directory user accounts.

Comment: *I want to link the SA account of the SQL SERVER to the Active Directory user accounts.* Umm... no, you don't. The account `sa` is the standalone SQL Server administrator account. It has no business with AD users. At all. To grant AD accounts access to your database enable mixed-mode authentication and actually grant permissions to the AD groups or users.

Comment: Also, what do you mean you "created a GPO, which groups these users"? GPOs are for applying configuration to AD users or computers, not for grouping users. That's what AD group objects are for.